# Adobe Flash - make all instances on stage unique

Tags: flash, adobe

In my flash doc, I have some movieclips that I use them as containers.
but the problem is that all the movieclips on the stage are instances of "Symbol 1" in the library.
I was wondering if there's an easy way to make them all different on the library, so if I'll edit one movieclip, this is the only movieclip who will change, and not all of them.
I know I can just create new movieclip everytime, but this is a lot of work because there are more than 50 containers in my project.
Any suggestions?

Comment: The fact that you need modify movieclips generally means you need unique templates, so "a lot of work" is required

Comment: so I was wondering if there's a command to flash that does it automatically...?

Comment: I don't use Flash since 2011 but I don't remember such a command. You can eventually create one symbol with different graphics in different keyframes, then add it to the stage programmatically (search for attachMovie, duplicateMovieClip, etc.)

Comment: There was this options too, sorry my AS is a little rusty: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b8ea63-7fee.html   :-)

Comment: https://www.the-flying-animator.com/duplicate-symbol.html